# How do i groupby portions of a column name for a box plot?

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, boxplot, pandas-groupby

I am looking to `groupby` a subset of column names to create boxplots in python pandas.

I have the following dataset:

```
local_term_1year | regional_term_1year | local_term_2year | regional_term_2year      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
30               | 30                  | 40               | 50 
20               | 40                  | 50               | 60
```

I am hoping to create two grouped boxplot graphs, one for 1year and another for 2year. Also if possible I'd like to color each boxplot according to the local/regional tag.

So far I have been able to extract the suffix and prefix from each column into a separate table:

```
column              | year  | region
---------------------------------------
local_term_1year    | 1year | local
regional_term_1year | 1year | regional
local_term_2year    | 2year | local
regional_term_2year | 2year | regional
```

I am not sure if this additional dataframe will help with the boxplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your pd.DataFrame is called `df`, we can do this the following way:

```
new_df = df.melt(var_name='col', value_name='table_value')
new_df['region'] = new_df.col.str.split('_').str.get(0)
new_df['year'] = new_df.col.str.split('_').str.get(-1)
```

We can then use [`seaborn.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot) to create the boxplot you asked for:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(data=new_df, x='year', y='table_value', hue='region')
```

DISCLAIMER: I have not tested this code - if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can test it but it should work as is. There is a particularly helpful guide for how to create such an example for a pandas question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536193/7480990).

Comment: This is great. I updated varname to var_name in melt and removed kind from sns.boxplot.

Comment: Oh, yeah -  I was originally going to go with factorplot. Glad you could figure it out though!